# Dimension does not appear in GA custom report

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Why might dimension not appear in GA custom report?

I created a custom report, then created a tab, then in the tab I picked a metric and five dimensions, I save it all, go to see what my report table looks like, but dimensions do not appear. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]
[image]

I am using GTM to pass the data to GA, it may be that I have to setup something there first. If it is so, what should I setup then?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The report type you've selected (or rather defaulted to) is Explorer, which returns one dimension and the graph over time, with links on the dimension values that allow you to drill down. By selecting the report type Flat Table, all dimensions are returned but no time series graph is plotted. Please note though, if you pull Custom Dimensions into a Custom Report and there is no value set for that hit (or session depending on the CD scope) then it will report no info, so you can end up with some funky results.

[image]